# Can I remove or change the link between YouTube and Google+?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I have a Google+ account, and I have a YouTube account that created a linked Google+ page on my Google+ account. In my YouTube settings, there is no link to disconnect the Google+ page (as seen in the screenshot below). I can’t delete the Google+ page while the YouTube account is connected to it.

Is it possible either to separate my YouTube account from Google+ entirely or to link it instead to my main Google+ account? If the latter, can I keep my YouTube username?

[image: Screenshot from my YouTube settings page with no link to disconnect from Google+]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google+ was retired in April, 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 14 days have passed since you connected to Google+ with your YouTube account, you cannot reverse the change. See this article [Switch back to your old YouTube username](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657858?hl=en).

> New channels created with a Google+ page or profile don't have an old username and can't disconnect Google+.
>
> Channels with an old username that have linked to a Google+ page (not profile) can only switch back to a YouTube username within 14 days after linking.

Comment: It'd be great if you could include a source for this.

Comment: Yes, source, please. If this is true, I guess that’s that.

Comment: Added source article

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you create your YouTube account:

> If your channel had a traditional YouTube username, you can disconnect your channel from Google+ and switch back to your YouTube username:
>
> - Make sure you're signed into YouTube. If your channel is connected to a Google+ page, make sure you sign in with the page owner's Google Account and switch into the channel.
> - Go to YouTube account settings
> - Click the link that includes disconnect Google+, found below your email address.
> - You will then be asked to confirm that you want to revert your YouTube channel to your old username. Click OK and your identity will be reset to your old username. Your old avatar (if you had one) will be restored as well.

Source: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657858

Comment: My YouTube account was created pre-Google and later connected to Google+, but like I said, **there is no link to disconnect it**. See this [screenshot](http://cl.ly/SJRe)—it should be between the two lines, and it’s not.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to which Google+ product your channel is connected to on https://www.youtube.com/account_transfer_channel.

To remove Google+ from your channel completely, you need to either delete the Google+ product, or move your channel to a Google Brand account. Brand accounts are effectively Google+ pages but without the social network part of Google+.

If you have created your channel after October 2016, you don't have anything Google+ connected to it anyways.